# How to limit SQL-result and take avg?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, limit, average

I'm using this SQL-Query to select all values of a specific wireless sensor node to plot charts depending on a timestamp.

```
SELECT * FROM measurement 
        WHERE nodeId = :nodeId 
        AND datetime BETWEEN :datetimestart 
        AND :datetimeend
```

The queried data are send to clients via AJAX. If the timestamp is selected over a long range, the array gets to big and datatransfer needs a long time. It would be much better if the array is limited by 100 entrys. Only limiting the query by 100 wouldn't solve the problem.

What I need to do is selecting the whole rows of the timestamp and take the average value of 100 different inner timestamps. The inner timestamps should be dynamic and depending of the outer timestamp.

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. Is it possible to select 100 average data depending on a timestamp with a SQL-query? Or do I need to parse the array with PHP?

**EDIT:**
structure of table measurement:

```
ID          nodeID      humidity    temperature  pressure    voltage     datetime
20519       Node1       46.66       21.39        1013.9      3.313       2017-05-20 10:54:00
20520       Node1       46.87       21.37        1013.9      3.321       2017-05-20 10:54:15
20521       Node1       46.55       21.35        1013.9      3.321       2017-05-20 10:54:30
20522       Node1       46.45       21.35        1013.8      3.321       2017-05-20 10:54:45
20523       Node1       46.68       21.35        1013.9      3.321       2017-05-20 10:55:00
20524       Node1       47.07       21.35        1013.8      3.314       2017-05-20 10:55:15
20525       Node1       47.41       21.36        1013.9      3.321       2017-05-20 10:55:30
20526       Node1       47.51       21.37        1013.9      3.314       2017-05-20 10:55:45
20527       Node1       47.53       21.36        1013.8      3.321       2017-05-20 10:56:00
20528       Node1       46.6        21.33        1013.9      3.321       2017-05-20 10:56:15
20529       Node1       47.14       21.33        1013.9      3.314       2017-05-20 10:56:30
20530       Node1       47.13       21.33        1013.9      3.313       2017-05-20 10:56:46
20531       Node1       48.22       21.36        1013.9      3.321       2017-05-20 10:57:01
20532       Node1       49.96       21.39        1013.9      3.321       2017-05-20 10:57:16
20533       Node1       49.49       21.43        1013.9      3.321       2017-05-20 10:57:31
20534       Node1       49.53       21.49        1014.0      3.321       2017-05-20 10:57:46
```

**EDIT 2** I wrote a pythontool to creat the sqlite database:

```
    import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('/var/www/sqliteDatabases/database_sdr.db')                   #connect to database "database.db"
cur = conn.cursor()                                     #create a cursor
cur.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')                 #enables the FOREIGN KEY constraint    


#______create table for temperature and humidity with date and time______
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE measurement(
                ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                nodeId text,
                humidity float,
                temperature float,
                pressure float,
                voltage float,
                datetime text)''')
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Both are possible. Doing it within the query will make the query more complex, and it will take longer to execute. Using PHP can be quite efficient. It all depends on the exact structure of your data table, which you haven't told us. I would try both, and see which performs, and looks, the best.

Comment: Thank you@KIKOSoftware for the fast response. For me it would be better to do this task by a complex SQL-Query instead of parsing the array with PHP. My problem is that I dont know how the SQL-statement should look like. I would be very thankful if you could give me an example

Comment: Could you give the structure of the table? What you've given now is the content of the table. That does give hints at the possible structure, but doesn't tell me the types of the columns, etc. A structure could be written as the SQL query to create the table. What is the reason you prefer a complex SQL query over some simple PHP?

Comment: Ok, I see that `datetime` is of type TEXT. I cannot see what's stored in that text, but you cannot operate on a text as if it is a date/time column. You have to use either the DATETIME or TIMESTAMP type. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html So that would be your first step. (I assume you're using MySQL, is that correct? It is probably sqlite3?)

Comment: The mainreason why I prefer the SQL-way is the clarity of programming style. Furthermore I'm writing my Bachelor-Thesis about the application and it's much easier for readers to understand the SQL-statement, as some hardcoded object oriented PHP codes.

 
I'm using the lightweight SQLite database. Working with datetime as text type is still possible in SQL, it only needs to be in the right format. In the format which I'm using there are no problems with comparison of datetime.

Comment: Yes, it is SQLite3, and I see you have to use TEXT in that. In my honest opinion complex SQL queries can be very hard to understand. Next time please specify you're using SQLite, because it is quite different from MySQL. The latter is used by 90% of people working with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following SQLite query we compute `period` for each row and use that to group the results by:

```
SELECT AVG(humidity) AS avgHumidity,
       AVG(temperature) AS avgTemperate,
       AVG(pressure) AS avgPressure,
       AVG(voltage) AS avgVoltage,
       round(100*(julianday(datetime)-julianday(:datetimestart))/
             (julianday(:datetimeend)-julianday(:datetimestart))) AS period   
FROM measurement 
WHERE nodeId = :nodeId AND 
      datetime BETWEEN :datetimestart AND :datetimeend
GROUP BY period
```

So basically you need to group your results. Several notes:

- I used the `julianday()` function to be able to add, subtract and
  divide, this might not be the correct way to do this in SQLite3.
- I reuse `:datetimestart` and `:datetimeend` several times. In MySQL
  this is not allowed. I don't know if it is allowed in SQLite3. If it 
  is not simply rename them `:datetimeend1`, `:datetimeend2` etc.
- This is only a untested push in the right direction. You need to work out the details yourself.

Comment: Note that I just corrected a bug in the computation of the period.

Comment: Wow *_* this was very helpful and it also worked! I need to get familiar with this statement. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. I'm surprised you got it working at all, and so fast. :-)

Comment: I needed to format the period back to the datetime. But now it works fine, I also programmed it in PHP, both works now. If you want to check the chart-plot, go to twinzy.hopto.org/test at the bottom. 
Using PHP:`$arraysize = count($data);
  $avgrows = intval($arraysize / 100);
  for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
   $total = 0;
   for($k = 0; $k<$avgrows; $k++){
    $total = $total + $data[$k*$i][$param];
   }
   $datetime[$i]  = $data[$k*$i]['datetime'];
   $avg[$i]   = $total/$avgrows;
  }
  $data = array(
   $param   => $avg,
   'datetime'  => $datetime
  );`

Comment: The link didn't work. Have you tested which is faster? SQLite or PHP? In PHP you could try to use `array_sum()` and one loop instead of two nested loops.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that the webserver is not online. My roommate forogt the router password so I'm not able to free the port :-D Actually the SQL-statement is a little bit faster (370ms to load ), but if the database gets filled with many more measures, the PHP-solution should be faster( Now: 375ms to load). I will try it later with `array_sum()`. I'm very thunkfull for your efforts! Enjoy the weekend ;-)